# Absolute retracts in $T_4$ spaces

Tags: general-topology

> **Definition:** A space $R$ is an *absolute retract* iff given any $T_4$-space $X$, any closed $A\subseteq X$  and $f:A\to R$ continuous, then $f$ has an extension to $X$.
>
> **Theorem:** A $T_4$-space is an absolute retract iff it is a retract of every $T_4$-space in which it can be embedded as a closed subset.

Let $R$ be a $T_4$-space and absolute retract. W.l.o.g., we are going to suppose $R\subseteq X$, where $X$ is $T_4$ and $R$ is closed in $X$. The identity $i:R\to R$ is continuous, then it has an extension to $X$ and clearly it is a retract $X\to R$.

I can't prove the other implication yet.

Let $R$ be a $T_4$ space with the property: $R$ is a retract of every $T_4$-space in which $R$ can be embedded as a closed subset. And let $X$ be a $T_4$-space, $A$ closed in $X$ and $f:A\to R$ continuous.

How can we construct a $T_4$-space in which $R$ is a closed subspace, in order to use its property?

Comment: Not sure whether it matters, but which nomenclature are you using, is a normal space one that is $T_4$ and $T_1$, or is a $T_4$ space one that is normal and $T_1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer $T_4$ space is normal and $T_1$. This problem is from Willard's General Topology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the space $X \sqcup_f R$ which is defined by quotienting the disjoint union $X\sqcup R$ by the relation that identifies each $a \in A$ with its image $f(a) \in R$. The hypothesis implies there exists a retract $r: X \sqcup_f R \rightarrow R$ and the extension $\tilde{f}:X \rightarrow R$ of $f$ can be defined by the restriction of $r$ to $X \subset X \sqcup_f R$.

Comment: I don't see how to embedd $R$ into $X\cup _f R$. I just think about the canonical map, which sends every $x\in R$ to its equivalence class, but this is not injective for there could be one $a\in R\cap A$, and then $a$ and $f(a)$ are in the same class but they're not need be equal.

Comment: By "$X \cup R$" I meant the disjoint union $X \sqcup R$. I'll make the necessary edits. In this case, your map is indeed injective.

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't prove that space is $T_4$ and then, accidentally, I found information about this space and read a nice proof using Tietze's theorem. For references it is called adjunction space.
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-901-introduction-to-topology-fall-2004/lecture-notes/notes_g.pdf